# tesseract and opencv gives error - Image too large

Tags: java, docker, opencv, tesseract

I have a a spring boot application running in a docker container which has tesseract installed on it.

In the java program, I am using opencv to preprocess an image as follows

```
MatOfByte mat = new MatOfByte(myByteArraySource);
Mat adaptive = new Mat();
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(mat, adaptive, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 7);

// convert to BufferedImage
MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", adaptive, matOfByte);
BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(matOfByte.toArray()));

// run tesseract
tesseract.doOCR(bf);
```

but running `tesseract.doOCR(bf);`
gives error: Image too large: (1, 146327)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
What's strange is the file size is only 146kb so I don't know why tesseract considers it too large?

Also, if I remove the adaptiveThreshold step and perform `imencode` on mat directly, then the tesseract scan works.

I have tried with both openjdk:11 and openjdk:8-jdk-alpine, they both give the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So I realize my mistake was interpreting the error (1, 146327) as the file size, where it's really the dimensions.

Instead of creating and using `MatOfByte` directly, I need to use the `imdecode` function

`Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(os.toByteArray(), ...)`

This correctly returns the size (e.g. 400,400 rather than 1,146327)